# How to use a Tika custom parser in a jar file?

Tags: java, maven, apache-tika

I'm trying to write a custom Apache Tika parser (for DICOM medical images), and package it as a plugin in a jar file.

I'm following the instructions from http://tika.apache.org/1.18/parser_guide.html, and took these projects as models:

- https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava (the tika part),
- https://github.com/Gagravarr/MPXJ-Tika.

So, I created a Maven project, wrote a parser class and a `org.apache.tika.parser.Parser` file in the `resources` folder, built the project with `mvn install`, and I now have a jar file.

My question is, how do I make Tika use this new parser? The instructions on the [Tika wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/3rd%20party%20parser%20plugins) say:

> To install a plugin, download it according to instructions below and
>   drop the jar(s) on your classpath. Tika will auto detect the plugin.

I tried to do this with `java -classpath /path/to/my-parser.jar ...` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
java -classpath /path/to/my-parser.jar -jar tika-app-1.18.jar --list-parsers
```

doesn't list the new parser, for instance.

I'm not a java person, and I'm really not sure about what "drop the jar on your classpath" means. I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction! Thanks.

Comment: You can't combine `-jar` and `-classpath` - it's a java command line tool limitation

Comment: @Gagravarr  Ok, thanks. So can I do it on the command line ? I put both in the classpath?

Comment: Yup, something like `java -classpath tika-app.jar:my-extra-parser.jar org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --list-parsers` should do it

Comment: @Gagravarr: Thank you so much, it works! Don't you want to make your comment an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sadly made a common Java newbie mistake - for various historic reasons the `java` program won't accept both `-jar` and `-classpath` options, and will ignore the `-classpath` parts you've given.

If you want to run the Apache Tika App on the command line, with an extra parser jar or two added, what you need to do is something like:

```
java -classpath tika-app.jar:my-extra-parser.jar org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --list-parsers
```

That calls the main Tika App entry point (the default with `-jar`) when running with *both* the Tika App jar *and* your custom extra jar on the classpath.

You may also find the [Troubleshooting Apache Tika guide from the Tika wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika) useful when developing custom plugins like this!